# how do i add variants as keys in a hashmap

Tags: rust, sdl-2

im using the sdl2 rust crate and i want to add events to a hashmap

like in this code snipped

```
let event_hashmap : HashMap<sdl2::event::Event,i8> =  Hashmap::new();
event_hashmap.insert(sdl2::event::Event::Quit,12)

for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
if event_hashmap.contains_key(event){
     println!("should prnint 12 when x is pressed")
```

but  this doesnt work and i get the following error

> error[E0423]: expected value, found struct variant
> sdl2::event::Event::Quit

Comment: `Quit` seem to be a struct (which is a variant of the `enum Event`). The value of it would be something like `...Quit { ..... }`

Comment: I just looked up the [docs](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.30.0/sdl2/event/enum.Event.html). It would be similar to `...Quit { 1234 }`, where `1234` is a timestamp. Not sure why you are creating the event manually, though. You are supposed to *receive* it.

Comment: i want to make an inputsystem where the event is the key in the hashmap and the action is the value

Comment: Then you will have to use some other type as the key. `Quit` by itself is not a value.

Comment: why then does it work in a match statement?

Comment: What does it have to do with `match`? `match` is performing pattern matching and "deconstructing" the *value*. I suggest to leave SDL aside for now, and do some cleaner Rust exercises.

Comment: because you can do something like this in match     `match event {
        Event::KeyDown {..} => { /*...*/ },
        _ => ()
    }` so why cant it be done anywhere else?

Comment: In your example `Event::KeyDown {..}` is a value (a pattern a value is matched against, to be precise). `Event::KeyDown` is not

Comment: the thing is that it asks me to add a timestamp to it when i add the Quit{..} key inside the hashmap so comparing the two wouldnt work that way is there another why to do this can i deconstruct the event somehow?

Comment: @rgfrtzwerf You will probably have to map the SDL event to your own enum, and use that enum as the key.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use events as keys in your `HashMap` because an event contains the time at which it occurred, which you obviously can't know beforehand. You can however use [`mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html) to get an integer representation of the enum variant.